# Does foreign key have to be primary key in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Can we use any other unique column as foreign key in django model?

Comment: From the docs: `ForeignKey.to_field¶
The field on the related object that the relation is to. By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object. If you reference a different field, that field must have unique=True.` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Column must be **unique=True.**

To reference this column, specify **to_fied** attribute on source column. Check below;

```
class Group (models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    otherid=models.IntegerField(unique=True)

class Member (models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    group=models.ForeignKey(Group,models.CASCADE,to_field='otherid')
```

Comment: Typo in bold. `to_field`. :-)